# Are GHC's Type Famlies An Example of System F-omega?

Tags: haskell, theory, ghc, type-families

I'm reading up about the Lambda-Cube, and I'm particularly interested in System F-omega, which allows for "type operators" i.e. types depending on types. This sounds a lot like GHC's type families. For example

```
type family Foo a
type instance Foo Int = Int
type instance Foo Float = ...
...
```

where the actual type depends on the type parameter `a`. Am I right in thinking that type families are an example of the type operators ala system F-omega? Or am I out in left field?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

System F-omega allows universal quantification, abstraction and application at *higher kinds*, so not only over types (at kind `*`), but also at kinds `k1 -> k2`, where `k1` and `k2` are themselves kinds generated from `*` and `->`. Hence, the type level itself becomes a simply typed lambda-calculus.

Haskell delivers slightly less than F-omega, in that the type system allows quantification and application at higher kinds, but not abstraction. Quantification at higher kinds is how we have types like

```
fmap :: forall f, s, t. Functor f => (s -> t) -> f s -> f t
```

with `f :: * -> *`. Correspondingly, variables like `f` can be instantiated with higher-kinded type expressions, such as `Either String`. The lack of abstraction makes it possible to solve unification problems in type expressions by the standard first-order techniques which underpin the Hindley-Milner type system.

However, *type families* are not really another means to introduce higher-kinded types, nor a replacement for the missing type-level lambda. Crucially, they must be *fully applied*. So your example,

```
type family Foo a
type instance Foo Int = Int
type instance Foo Float = ...
....
```

should not be considered as introducing some

```
Foo :: * -> * -- this is not what's happening
```

because `Foo` on its own is not a meaningful type expression. We have only the weaker rule that `Foo t :: *` whenever `t :: *`.

Type families do, however, act as a distinct type-level computation mechanism beyond F-omega, in that they introduce *equations* between type expressions. The extension of System F with equations is what gives us the "System Fc" which GHC uses today. Equations `s ~ t` between type expressions of kind `*` induce coercions transporting values from `s` to `t`. Computation is done by deducing equations from the rules you give when you define type families.

Moreover, you *can* give type families a higher-kinded return type, as in

```
type family Hoo a
type instance Hoo Int = Maybe
type instance Hoo Float = IO
...
```

so that `Hoo t :: * -> *` whenever `t :: *`, but still we cannot let `Hoo` stand alone.

The trick we sometimes use to get around this restriction is `newtype` wrapping:

```
newtype Noo i = TheNoo {theNoo :: Foo i}
```

which does indeed give us

```
Noo :: * -> *
```

but means that we have to apply the projection to make computation happen, so `Noo Int` and `Int` are provably distinct types, but

```
theNoo :: Noo Int -> Int
```

So it's a bit clunky, but we can kind of compensate for the fact that type families do not directly correspond to type operators in the F-omega sense.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer :-). I think I've learned more about the theory behind Haskell's (well, GHC's) type system in this answer than in anything else I've read on the internet so far.